# sound card not detected in Kali 2 Debian

Tags: audio, drivers, kali-linux, sound-card

I'm using Kali Linux 2.0 and have a problem with my audio card.

I tested many solutions like pulseaudio or alsamixer or upgrade packages but my problem is still not resolved.

I don't have any sound from OS or any media files.

Sound settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type in

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

and reboot.

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: pulseaudio is not a service

Comment: Are you sure pulseaudio is installed?

Comment: yes I'm sure and i can see channels and all channels are unmute

Comment: You try this workaround, reinstalling pulseaudio by apt-get remove  pulseaudio && reboot and apt-get install pulseaudio && reboot